Проблема с com.hzy.libp7zip
У меня старый код в андроид студио и там я импортировал файл aar этого модуля
но пишет ошибку:
public abstract class UnZipCallback implements IExtractCallback {
                                               ^
  symbol: class IExtractCallback

